# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

```
public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Determine a size threshold below which compression is not performed
    int sizeThreshold = 1024; // for example, consider images smaller than 1KB

    if (inImage.getByteCount() > sizeThreshold) {
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    } else {
        // Handle small images differently or skip compression
        // For example, you might simply use the original image without compression
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes); // Use PNG format for small images
    }


    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

#Getting crash while compressing the image in Redmi devices. Android versions 10 mostly.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Uri saveImageAndGetUri(Context context, Bitmap imageBitmap) {
File imageFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "image.jpg");
try {
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

return Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
}